# Python - Check if a user input is in another user input

Tags: python-3.x

Python 3.5

I am writing a program that essentially asks the user to input a sentence (no punctuation). Then it will ask for the user to input a word. I want the program to identify whether or not that word is in the original sentence (I refer to the sentence as string 1 (Str1) and the word as string 2 (Str2)). With the current code I have, it will only ever tell me that the word has been found and I can't seem to find a way to fix it.

```
str1 = input("Please enter a full sentence: ")
print("Thank you, You entered:" , str1)

str2 = input("Now please enter a word included in your sentence in any way you like: ")

if (str2,str1):
    print("That word was found!")
else:
    print("Sorry, that word was not found")
```

If anyone has any advice on that might help me and anyone else interested in this topic then that would be greatly appreciated! :)

Although as this is a learning process for me, i don't really want straight forward "here's the code you should have..." but if that is all that can be offered then i would be happy to take it.

Comment: Like the answer below. You use the IF firstString IN secondString    operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if str2 in str1:
    print("That word was found!")
else
    print("Sorry, that word was not found")
```

Is this what you are looking for ?

The in checks if str2 is literally in str1. Since str1 is a list of words it checks if str2 is inside str1.

Comment: yes that worked for me, I thought I had tried that before and it hadn't worked. But it did, cheers! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided works ok, but if you want word matching, will provide a false positive given:

EDIT: just spotted the prompt asks for a word in the sentence... In my experience, these sorts of things are most prone to breakage when they interact with a human, so I try to plan accordingly.

```
str1 = "This is a story about a man"
str2 = "an"
```

where:

```
broken_string = str1.split()

if str2.lower() in [x.lower() for x in broken_string]:
    print("The word {} was found!".format(str2))
else:
    print("{} was not found in {}.".format(str2, str1))
```

Gets a little more complicated (fun) with punctuation.